# Laptop nvidia geforce turned into intel graphics card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hardware-failure, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics

I am experiencing something strange in one of my laptops that I haven't seen before. The laptop is an [ASUS K52JC](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K52JC/#specifications), has an Nvidia Geforce 310M. I have it setup as a dual boot with both windows 7 and windows 8.

It has worked fine for about 2 years. However, today windows suddenly crashed. After a reboot, the nvidia control panel complained that no nvidia graphics card was found. After running windows update, it now has a, fully functional, Intel HD graphics card. I first thought it was a software issue, but after rebooting to windows 7, exactly the same thing happened.

Is it possible that the graphics card downgrades itself to an intel HD graphics when the nvidia card breaks down? Or is this some a software/driver problem?

Comment: Interesting.  The processor in your laptop does have an integrated gpu, but I am surprised that it could "take over" without support in the bios and hardware.  Have you checked the bios to see if you can choose which graphics card to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible for a graphics card to downgrade itself.   You will probably find there is a GPU (graphics card) built into your CPU as well as an external one with the NVIDIA Chipset.   Somehow it looks like you have managed to force the system to run off the internal card.

Have you tried downloading and reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers for your card ?

Comment: My nvidia card has completely disappeared. There is no sign of it in the device manager. When I try to install nvidia drivers, it just tells me that no nvidia graphics card has been detected.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 forced an "enhancement" upon me several months ago.  At that time, the new W10 would not let me see my nVidia card.  I tried updating drivers (already up to date but what the heck, maybe reinstalling them would help), I tried going to PnP and forcing Win10 to recognize the nVidia card, all to no avail.  The ONLY thing that made this Dell XPS Laptop work again with the nVidia card was to REVERT to the older W10.  As far as I'm concerned, MS does not offer an update or enhancement that is worth the pain I have endured to keep my laptop functioning.